# How to properly configure my GWT Activity and ActivityMapper?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform, gwt-activities

I have the following classes:

```
// The "backing bean" for DashboardDisplay.ui.xml (which is omitted for brevity).
public class DashboardDisplay extends Composite implements AcceptsOneWidget {
    private EventBus eventBus;
    private PlaceController placeController;
    private IsWidget content = null;

    public DashboardDisplay(EventBus eventBus, PlaceController placeController) {
        super();

        setEventBus(eventBus);
        setPlaceController(placeController);
    }

    // Getters and setters for all properties
    // ...

    @Override
    public void setWidget(IsWidget widget) {
        setContent(widget);
    }
}

public class DashboardActivity extends AbstractActivity {
    private AcceptsOneWidget container;
    private ActivityManager manager;
    private DashboardDisplay display;

    public DashboardActivity(AcceptsOneWidget container, ActivityManager manager,
        DashboardDisplay display) {
        super();

        setContainer(container);
        setManager(manager);
        setDisplay(display);

        // I *believe* this ensures that the 'panel' passed in to the
        // start method is always our 'container'. Yes?
        manager.setDisplay(container);
    }

    // Getters and setters for all properties
    // ...

    @Override
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
        display.setEventBus(eventBus);
        panel.setWidget(display);
    }
}

public class DashboardActivityMapper implements ActivityMapper {
    private DashboardActivity activity = null;

    // Getters and setter for activity.

    @Override
    public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
        // Leaving arguments null because I'm confused about the object graph
        // (read below).
        return new DashboardActivity(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

So I'm *starting* to have some semblance of an understanding of the Activities framework, but still so new to it that when I try to venture away from the *Hello, GWT* examples, I run into obstacles with the API almost instantly.

In my app's main GWT module, `MyWebAppModule`, I'm trying to instantiate and configure these 3 objects. But because I'm still unsure of how to use their API, I'm running into implementation problems:

```
public class MyWebAppModule implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // I'll worry about DI and getting GIN to work after
        // I figure this basic stuff out.
        EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
        PlaceController placeController = new PlaceController(eventBus);
        MyWebAppPlaceHistoryMapper placeMapper = new MyWebAppPlaceHistoryMapper();
        HomePlace homePlace = new HomePlace();

        // WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS
        DashboardActivityMapper activityMapper = new DashboardActivityMapper();
        ActivityManager manager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper, eventBus);

        // Really not sure how to inject/configure this properly.
        DashboardActivity dashboardActivity = new DashboardActivity(null, null, null);
        // WHERE THE PROBLEM ENDS

        PlaceHistoryHandler historian = new PlaceHistoryHandler(placeMapper);
        historian.register(placeController, eventBus, homePlace);
        historian.handleCurrentHistory();
    }
}
```

1. Clearly, I haven't implemented `DashboardActivityMapper` and `DashboardActivity` correctly, so it's causing problems when I try to instantiate and wire their instances inside `MyWebAppModule#onModuleLoad`. Could someone help me implement this correctly? Once I get a working example down, I'm sure I'll be able to connect the rest of the "dots" in the Activities framework.
2. Unless I'm missing something, the `ActivityManager manager` above doesn't seem to get added to any other class. Is this correct? Will GWT ensure that it stays alive in memory so that it is always listening on the `eventBus` I pass it for `PlaceChangeEvent`s? Or do I need to add/register it to anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `DashboardActivityMapper` is responsible of creating and returning a `DashboardActivity` when a given place (e.g. the `HomePlace`) is reached. Is this the information you're missing?
   See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#ActivityMapper
2. As long as the `EventBus` has a handle to the `ActivityManager` (so it can dispatch events to it). However, `ActivityManager` registers itself on the `EventBus` in its `setDisplay` method, when called with a non-null value (and de-registers itself when a `null` is passed to `setDisplay`), and you don't call `setDisplay` (which incidentally mean that the activities wouldn't even be displayed)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - I now understand the root of my confusion. I *do* understand the following: the `DashboardActivityMapper` is responsible for creating and returning a `DashboardActivity`. An `ActivityManager` is then given the `DashboardActivityMapper`, and when it receives a `HomePlace` off the registered `EventBus`, it knows to call th `DashboardActivity`'s `start` method...

Comment: (continued)...If so here is the root of my problem: **When the `ActivityManager` calls `getActivity(homePlace)` and returns a `DashboardActivity`, what happens to the `DashboardActivity`? How does it relate to the `DashboardActivity#start(AcceptsOneWidget,EventBus)` invocation?**. Thanks again!

Comment: `ActivityManager` will call the activity's `start` method, passing in the value you passed to its `setDisplay`